# tkz-euclide fill parts of a circle

Tags: tikz-pgf, tkz-euclide

I'm currently able to draw this image with the following code:
[image: Circles]

```latex
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \tkzInit[xmax=3,ymax=3,xmin=-3,ymin=-3]
    \tkzGrid
    \tkzAxeXY
    \tkzDefPoint(0,0){A}
    \tkzDefPoint(1,0){B}
    \tkzDefPoint(2,0){C}
    \tkzDefCircle[through](A,B)
    \tkzDefCircle[through](A,C)
    \tkzDrawCircle[color=red](A,C)
    \tkzDrawCircle[color=red](A,B)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

And I want to fill parts of the outer circle, but it shouldn't overwrite the inner circle. Basically like this:
[image: Filled Circle]

How could I do this with tkz-euclide or any other tikz library?

Comment: Please make your code compilable.

Comment: is this what you want? `\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[gray!20] (-3,-3) grid[step=5mm] (3,3); 
\fill[cyan] 
(2,0) arc(0:90:2) --(0,1) arc(90:0:1)--cycle
(-2,0) arc(180:270:2) --(0,-1) arc(270:180:1)--cycle;
\draw[violet,thick] (0,0) circle(1) circle(2);
\draw[blue] (-3,0)--(3,0) (0,-3)--(0,3); 
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not too familiar with `tkz-euclide` but with just Ti*k*Z it is very easy.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}
 \clip (0,-3) -| (-3,0) -| (3,3) -| cycle;
 \fill[gray,even odd rule] circle[radius=2] circle[radius=1];
\end{scope}
\draw[red]  circle[radius=2] circle[radius=1];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: this is perfect, thanks!